# How to detect if cursor is hovering over text inside DataGridViewCell

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to display some custom tool-tips in my DataGridView depending on whether the cursor is hovering over the text of the cell or not.

The reason for this is because sometimes cells have very little text in them and showing a tooltip on simply the `MouseEnter` event would basically make it so that there's a tooltip whenever the user's cursor is anywhere on the grid. Which would be super annoying.

Is there a way to detect if the user's cursor is actually on the text itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following logic should work:

```
private bool IsCursorOverCellText(DataGridView dgv, int columnIndex, int rowIndex)
{
    if (dgv[columnIndex, rowIndex] is DataGridViewCell cell)
    {
        var cursorPosition = dgv.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
        var cellAreaWithTextInIt =
            new Rectangle(dgv.GetCellDisplayRectangle(columnIndex, rowIndex, true).Location, cell.GetContentBounds(rowIndex).Size);

        return cellAreaWithTextInIt.Contains(cursorPosition);
    }

    return false;
}

private void DataGridView_CellMouseMove(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex < 0 || e.RowIndex < 0)
        return;

    if (sender is DataGridView dgv)
    {
        if (IsCursorOverCellText(dgv, e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex))
            dgv[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Red; 
        else
            dgv[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.White;
    }
}
```

Here's a demo:

[image: ontexthover]